# Attaching header to visiting a url by default

Tags: javascript, html, routes

Short version: How do I attach a header to the request sent to my server when someone lands on some `url.com/path`?

Hello, I'm trying to set up some basic routing and user authentication on my site `http://foo.bar/`. When they visit `/profile` I am sending a `GET` request to my node server and have a middleware that is checking for the `Authorization` token in the header of the request. On a redirect from somewhere else in the app, I can make the request using XMLHttpRequest to attach the header and load the resource, but I want to make it loadable if someone is just typing `/profile` into the browser. How would I go about checking for/attaching a header that should already exist in `localstorage` when someone simply loads the page and before I make the request to the server?

Comment: You can't run JavaScript when someone is typing in your sites URL, you need to change the way your authentication works on the backend

Comment: You can do this with a cookie - basically the contents of the cookie are sent with every request, regardless of how they got there.

Comment: I do not know what language you are using for the backend, but seeing as this logic you want to deal with in the backend I would recommend checking about something similar to a `session` object in ASP.Net or `$_SESSION` for PHP.